# How to load schema and data for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration, database-migration

How to load schema and data for my production rails app into a different machine.
I would like to converge all migrations done so far into a single migration file and point the new instance to a snapshot of the prod db. How to solve

Comment: What about simple database migration? What is your database?

Comment: MySQL is the database and would like to merge all migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the schema and do `rake db:schema:load`. You can also paste the schema.rb contents into a migration, but make sure to delete all other migrations. However keep in mind that there is really no reason to do so, just leave the old migrations as they are.

To import test data use this gem: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db .

Comment: If I use a single migration file with the contents of schema.rb what needs to go as part of the down method, where I need to remove all tables.

Comment: It will probably be sufficient to just remove the tables. But again, this is not really a good practice.

Comment: yaml_db doesn't seem to dump at all, it just keeps running for more than 6 hours, not sure how to enable debug logs.